# xrmtoolbox won't load due to this cinteros errror

Tags: xrmtoolbox

I downloaded the latest and get the following error though this dll does not appear to be on my computer. I unblocked the zip yet I still get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it my deleting all the old config data in the environment variable, %APPDATA%\MscrmTools\XrmToolBox .